# Java Load Custom Font File (.ttf)

Tags: java, fonts, custom-font

I have used this code below, and it comes up with this stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: font.ttf (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at com.ominious.core.graphics.Assets.getFont(Assets.java:55)
    at com.ominious.core.graphics.Assets.loadImages(Assets.java:37)
    at com.ominious.core.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:63)
    at com.ominious.core.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ominious.core.graphics.Assets.loadImages(Assets.java:49)
    at com.ominious.core.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:63)
    at com.ominious.core.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I use this code (I call the method in a resource file that I know works)

```
    private static Font getFont(String name) throws Exception {

    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream(name));

    return font;
}
```

And I call it here:

```
try {
        FONT = getFont("font.ttf");

        tileSprites = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mom.gif"));

        SPLASH_BACKGROUND = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/swag.gif"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Game.logger.log(LogType.ERROR_STACKTRACE);

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(The class above works, my image loads)

Is there a reason why this doesn't work? Is there a better method? (And yes, I do have it in my directory)

Comment: Where is the font stored in relationship to the code trying to load it?

Comment: By the time of deployment, the `Font` will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't that difficult to load a font from resources the same way you are loading the images. I know this question was asked a year ago, but i hope to finally provide an answer.

Simply use the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html), which details how to load custom fonts into a `GraphicsEnvironment`. It should look something like the following:

```
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = null;
    try{
      ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
      ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, game.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/fantasy.TTF")));
    } catch(FontFormatException e){} catch (IOException e){}
```

Note: I use `classInstance.getClass().getResourceAsStream(String fileDir)` to load the file from my resources directory in the Jar file.

After registering the font with the graphics environment, the font is available in calls to `getAvailableFontFamilyNames()` and can be used in font constructors.

Hope this answers your question finally!

Answer (score 2):

Most probably because you're running this out of a jar, and there's no `File` object to get. Compare how you're loading your images with `getResourceAsStream`, which can find resources that are either unpacked as files (usually for development) or packaged into a jar. Use the same `getResourceAsStream` call in `createFont`.

Comment: I tried that, and it throws no stack trace, but the font ain't working. Could I have a piece of coce/method?

Comment: @user3141055 Then the problem isn't with the loading of the font but how you are using it