# Importing fonts into java (not using Swing)

Tags: java, fonts, import, awt

How do I import a font into a Java applet with AWT? I don't want a solution in Swing, so don't bother if that's your advice, thanks.

I know I would have to have the TTF file but then I don't know how to make my applet use the file for my text.

Comment: `java.awt.Font` is used by both AWT and Swing, so the process of loading the font is the same

Comment: So how do you import a custom made font file?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the font using [`Font#createFont(int, InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.InputStream))
   .  You can use it directly, but it's better if...
2. Register the font with the system [`GraphicsEnvironment#registerFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#registerFont(java.awt.Font))

As mentioned:

- [How can I use a custom font in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652344/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-java)
- [Java Load Custom Font File (.ttf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210204/java-load-custom-font-file-ttf)

**Updated...**

In order to be able to use a `Font` within a `Applet` context, you the `Font` file will need to be included within your applets Jar file.

You will then need to use something like...

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/font file");
```

Where the path is relative to your class files.

You would then use this to load the `Font`

Comment: Those links are hard to understand. How do I implement this?

Comment: I get an error, "cannot find symbol - class InputStream"

Comment: @user3414510 Java tutorial: [Lesson: Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: I'm very new to I/O. I have a file that leads to my OTF file now. I still don't understand how to use it in my applet though, even after looking at your links.