# How to use Fira Code as Font in my Program?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts

I am very interested in this font named 'Fira Code'. Are there any way or methods that I can use in order to set this font as a `Font` to my Java components (preferably in `JTextArea` and `JLabel`)? I have downloaded the font locally (thru Google Fonts) and I have found out that it was a `TrueType` font file (`.ttf` extension).

Is it possible to use this font?

Comment: [Java Load Custom Font File (.ttf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210204/java-load-custom-font-file-ttf) and [Font Awesome with Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177348/font-awesome-with-swing/24177458#24177458) might be place to start

Comment: I tried it. It seems the technique lies in registering the font as one of the font assets on the java project. However, I am still stuck on calling the font itself. :(

Comment: You tried what? You were given two suggestions. The "Font Awesome" link contains a complete example. If you can't get that to work how do you expect us to help? We can't guess what your code is like. Start with the working example to prove it works. Then use that knowledge and update your current application.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was on the icon my bad, I'm sorry. Thank you for the notice I am really big novice on this one

Comment: I shamed myself in disbelief, I should have made my brain pay attention more. I am very sorry. Thank you @camickr

Comment: And thnak you also @MadProgrammer the tip was awesome and working